# Tag Picker in SPFx

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-framework, fluent-ui

I am trying to use the FluentUI Tag picker on
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/pickers for one of my projects

Being a newbie , I am experiencing challenges implementing this on SPFx.
Also googled a lot for examples, no luck
I would really appreciate if anyone could help me with its implementation or examples if any

Comment: you ca check the code on the Fluent UI site. you can use exact same code.

Comment: If you are having problems with your code, it is often helpful if you post the section of code you are having problems with and/or any error messages you are getting, to give us a place to start from when trying to help you figure out what is wrong.  You can edit your question to add your code snippet.